# Download ms dependencies in command window

Tags: dll, dependencies, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have been having troubles getting my EXE files to run after creating them with python installer. They work fine when I execute them from the command window or double click the .py file, but do not run as an EXE file. I'm suspecting that it is because im missing the following dependencies that were displayed in the command prompt when compiling my python file with pyinstaller.

```
['api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll']
```

Is there a way for me to download them through the command window quickly? If not, where can I download these official dependencies?

Comment: If you were missing these dependencies, then you couldn't start it in the command windows as well.

Comment: Interesting. So why am I getting that I am missing all of these dependencies?